# How to add a book page: material types empty

Tags: 7, nodes

I run [a Drupal 7 website](http://preferans.de) since a year and have been always upgrading it - up to the version 7.10.

I have 2 Books and users' Blog at my web site. One of the Books is holding "Site Help" and "Imprint" stuff.

Now there have been a need to add to add 2 new pages "Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy" to that book.

I go to **/node/add** but there is a message that no "material types" have been defined.

But I don't remember deleting them. And when I go to **/admin/structure/types** I see both "Machine name: blog" and "book" defined there:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: And you are not able to add this kind of content since your update to 7.10?

Comment: I'm not sure since when. But I have 2 Drupal 7.10 installs: preferans.de and simplex.ru and both have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node/add` works for me, but try `admin/content/add`.  Also check that you are logged on as the administrator.

Comment: /admin/content/add displays a link to /node/add. And /node/add says there are no content types defined and displays link to /admin/structure/types/add. And when I go there I see the picture shown above (blog and book). But nowhere can I add a new book page. Yes, I'm admin.